# Dynamically added gridview's linkbutton not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has dynamically created columns.

Right now all the data is showing in its respective place but I am unable to get my link button to work. (Gridview disappears)

Here is my backend code, the gridview used is just an empty gridview

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
        tfield.HeaderText = "View";
        GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);
    }
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

string selectedID = null;
private void BindGrid(List<string> SelectedInfo)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    //Dynamically adding columns and setting first column added as ID
    selectedID = SelectedInfo[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedInfo.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(SelectedInfo[i], typeof(string)));
    }

    List<string[]> InfoList = getInfoList(SelectedInfo);

    for (int i = 0; i < InfoList.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(InfoList[i]);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {   //Adding link button to first column
        LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
        lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
        lnkView.Text = "View";
        lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;
        lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[selectedID].ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lnkView);
    }
}

protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Popup the selected row ID
    LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton);
    GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
    string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Row ID" + id + "')", true);
}

protected void CheckBoxList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> SelectedInfo = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList2.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            SelectedInfo.Add(CheckBoxList2.Items[i].Text);
        }
    }

    BindGrid(SelectedInfo);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `LinkButton` and I don't see where you call the `BindGrid` method.

Comment: Added missing method, also the templatefield is added on pageload and linkbuttons are added on GridView1_RowDataBound

Comment: Well, this code is relevant to the question you may want to show it.

Comment: Which one? I think I have added all the relevant codes

Comment: The CALL to the `BindGrid` method, and the `GridView1_RowDataBound` method. Don't you think this is relevant to the question? You are talking about a `LinkButton`, but there's no trace of it in the code you showed.

Comment: I Have already added them to the code (BindGrid() is in CheckBoxList2_SelectedIndexChanged)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create controls at runtime, you better use the `RowCreated` event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {   //Adding link button to first column
        LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
        lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
        lnkView.Text = "View";
        lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;
        lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row[selectedID].ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lnkView);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you have to bind your `GridView` on every postback inViewDetails the `Page_Load` event.

Anyway if your `GridView` disappears, it's just because you have to bind it again in the `ViewDetails` method.

Comment: I have moved the codes to RowCreated, but it doesn't change anything. Could the problem be the linkbutton code itself? Although I tried it on another example and it worked

Comment: So the `ViewDetails` event doesn't fire?

Comment: Yes, it destroys the gridview too

Comment: So you have to bind the gridview again inside the event. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry was working on something. As for this I added BindGrid() method into the ViewDetails method but the gridview still gets destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

### I hope below code will help you.

```
                     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                            {
                                if (!this.IsPostBack)
                                {
                                    TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
                                    tfield.HeaderText = "View";
                                    GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield);
                                }
                                this.BindGrid();
                            }
                            private void BindGrid()
                            {
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                                            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string))  });
                                dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
                                dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");

                                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                                GridView1.DataBind();
                            }

                            protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
                            {
                                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                                {
                                    LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
                                    lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
                                    lnkView.Text = "View";
                                    lnkView.Click += ViewDetails;
                                    lnkView.CommandArgument = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Id"].ToString();
                                    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lnkView);
                                }
                            }

                            protected void ViewDetails(object sender, EventArgs e)
                            {
                                LinkButton lnkView = (sender as LinkButton);
                                GridViewRow row = (lnkView.NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
                                string id = lnkView.CommandArgument;
                                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Id: " + id + "')", true);
                            }
```